# Ubuntu won't let me enter my root password

Tags: password, root

When I was installing a program, it said that I needed to run it as a normal account rather than an administrator account, and so, being the inexperienced person that I am, changed my account to Standard rather than Administrator.

When I went to change it back, I clicked `unlock`, and entered my password (the only password I have ever used for this computer), and it said that `my authentication attempt was unsuccessful`.

I've tried changing my password in the `recovery mode` before booting, and it still doesn't work. I can't install any programs without being admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to recover admin rights

Lifted from this [post](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo).

First you need to boot into *recovery mode*. If Ubuntu is the only system installed on your computer you need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>-Key while booting.

[image: The recovery-mode entry on a single OS system]

Select the "recovery mode"-entry which is usually the second one.

[image: The menu from the recovery mode]

- Select "root  Drop to root shell prompt".
- Enter `mount -o rw,remount /` to make your system writeable

### Repairing

Enter the following (replacing your-username with your actual username):

```
adduser your-username sudo
adduser your-username admin
```

Now your user will have his admin rights back. Enter

```
reboot
```

to reboot your system.

Comment: Ok I'll try that